# Chrome extension for erasing recent history with one click

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, history

Is there a Google Chrome extension for erasing recent history with one click from the toolbar?  I'm currently using [History Eraser](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/history-eraser/gjieilkfnnjoihjjonajndjldjoagffm/details?hl=en), but it's currently a 3-4 click process to clear my history for the last 4 hours using the extension due to the popup that displays ~ Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need an extension if CTRL+SHIFT+DEL + click OK works just as fast?

Comment: I prefer to erase my history with one hand using the touch pad / mouse, but thank you (I use a MacBook Pro)

Comment: Why not make it easier and simply not store local history at all?

Comment: I use my browser normally and then at times prefer to search / browse select content that I wish to erase the history of later.  Please trust I asked it for good reason.  If you disagree with my personal preferences, please feel free not to comment on those differences and focus on the original question.  There's a reason History Eraser and Click&Clean are popular as extensions in Chrome.  Thanks for your time and answer.

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/history-eraser/gjieilkfnnjoihjjonajndjldjoagffm?hl=en

Comment: That's the same link that's in my question.  The extension is misleading in the description - It doesn't actually clear your history in one click, instead it just opens an app.  I'm looking for a one click solution.